# Prevent toolbar from hiding when recyclerview has one item

Tags: android, toolbar, android-recyclerview, android-design-library

I have some, problem. The toolbar is hiding when recyclerview has few items (1,2,3,4). This is unwanted behavior.

How can i prevent the toolbar from hiding when recyclerview has only few item and there is no scroll on recyclerview?

**main_recyclerview.xml**

[GIF showing the problem](http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/6-20-2015/OxkZ-H.gif)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
     >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cities_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:onClick="addCity"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_white_36dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to prevent the RecyclerView from dispatching scrolling events to its parents.

```
     private class NoScrollTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnTouchListener{
            private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
            private long mStartClickTime;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        mStartClickTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        long clickDuration = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() - mStartClickTime;
                        if(clickDuration <= MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(v instanceof RecyclerView){
                    boolean isLastVisible = ((LinearLayoutManager)((RecyclerView) v).getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == ((RecyclerView) v).getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);

   boolean isFirstVisible =  ((LinearLayoutManager)((RecyclerView) v).getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);
                   return isLastVisible && isFirstVisible;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

This might not be right approach but it has the concise condition when the RecyclerView does not need to scroll.

```
((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
```

See also `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallow)` of RecyclerView parent (i.e `CoordinatorLayout`)

Another way to try to prevent any scrolling behavior is to register data observer to your `RecyclerView.Adapter` and using the condition above to toggle the `layout_scrollFlags` of your `Toolbar`:

```
     boolean isLastVisible = ((LinearLayoutManager)((RecyclerView) v).getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == ((RecyclerView) v).getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);

   boolean isFirstVisible =  ((LinearLayoutManager)((RecyclerView) v).getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);

                if(isFirstVisible && isLastVisible){
                    mOldScrollFlags = mOldScrollFlags == -1 ?  params.getScrollFlags() : mOldScrolFlags;
                    params.setScrollFlags(0);
                }else{
                    params.setScrollFlags(mOldScrollFlags);
                }
                mToolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

When you set scrolling flags to 0, the AppBarLayout will exclude that view from calculating it in the total flexible range.

Comment: What will be the initial value for mOldScrollFlags ?

Comment: `mOldScrollFlags = mOldScrollFlags == -1 ?  params.getScrollFlags() : mOldScrolFlags;` As you desire. :)